# How to show 0 when variable is negative

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple calculator. What I want to get is to show 0 value when calculations value is negative.

Here is the code:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var total = 0.0;
  $.each($(".amount"), function() {

    var amount = parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
    var multiply = parseFloat($(".multiply").val());
    if (amount && multiply)
      total += amount * multiply;
  });
  $.each($(".summable"), function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
  });
  $.each($(".minusable"), function() {
    total -= parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
  });
  $("#sum").val(total.toFixed(2))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount
<input type="text" class="amount" />
<br>
<select class="multiply">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<br>Sum 1
<input type="text" class="summable" />
<br>Sum 2
<input type="text" class="summable" />
<br>Minus 1
<input type="text" class="minusable" />
<br>Minus 2
<input type="text" class="minusable" />
<br>

<input id="sum" type="text" />
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Simply enter Minus values greater than Amount and Sum. You will get negative value as a result. Please point me how to show "0" when the result value is negative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `total = Math.max(0,total);`

Comment: Thanks to all answers. I'm very new to js so your help much appreciated. I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check in an if if the total is less than 0 if so set the total to 0.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var total = 0.0;
  $.each($(".amount"), function() {

    var amount = parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
    var multiply = parseFloat($(".multiply").val());
    if (amount && multiply)
      total += amount * multiply;
  });
  $.each($(".summable"), function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
  });
  $.each($(".minusable"), function() {
    total -= parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
    if(total<0)
      total=0;
  });
  $("#sum").val(total.toFixed(2))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount
<input type="text" class="amount" />
<br>
<select class="multiply">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<br>Sum 1
<input type="text" class="summable" />
<br>Sum 2
<input type="text" class="summable" />
<br>Minus 1
<input type="text" class="minusable" />
<br>Minus 2
<input type="text" class="minusable" />
<br>

<input id="sum" type="text" />
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Math.max()`, it'll return `0` if the other value is negative:

```
$("#sum").val( Math.max( total, 0 ).toFixed(2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another small thing:

```
if (total.toFixed(2) > 0)
  $("#sum").val(total.toFixed(2));
else
  $("#sum").val("0");
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var total = 0.0;
  $.each($(".amount"), function() {

    var amount = parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
    var multiply = parseFloat($(".multiply").val());
    if (amount && multiply)
      total += amount * multiply;
  });
  $.each($(".summable"), function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
  });
  $.each($(".minusable"), function() {
    total -= parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
  });
  if (total.toFixed(2) > 0)
    $("#sum").val(total.toFixed(2));
  else
    $("#sum").val("0");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount
<input type="text" class="amount" />
<br>
<select class="multiply">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<br>Sum 1
<input type="text" class="summable" />
<br>Sum 2
<input type="text" class="summable" />
<br>Minus 1
<input type="text" class="minusable" />
<br>Minus 2
<input type="text" class="minusable" />
<br>

<input id="sum" type="text" />
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the value is positive, if not then use 0.

```
$("#sum").val(total > 0 ? total.toFixed(2) : 0);
```

[**Ternary Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  var total = 0.0;
     $.each($(".amount"), function() {

       var amount = parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
       var multiply = parseFloat($(".multiply").val());
       if (amount && multiply)
          total += amount * multiply;
     });
    $.each($(".summable"), function() {
       total += parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
    });
    $.each($(".minusable"), function() {
      total -= parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
    });
    if(total < 0){
       total = 0; 
    }
    $("#sum").val(total.toFixed(2))
});
```